# https support for ffmpeg centos?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have installed ffmpeg on centos.But when I feed url with https like

```
ffmpeg -i https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/bucket/check.mp4 video.mp4
```

Error come

```
https protocol not found, recompile FFmpeg with openssl, gnutls, or securetransport enabled.
```

I know i have to enable this `--enable-openssl`,but when i am doing like this

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig"
./configure --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" --extra-cflags="-I$HOME/ffmpeg_build/include" --extra-ldflags="-L$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib -ldl" --bindir="$HOME/bin" --pkg-config-flags="--static" --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-openssl
```

It give me error like:

```
ERROR: opus not found
```

What should I do to enable https? Please help

Comment: Try harder. https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos

Answer (score 1):

The guide [FFmpeg Wiki: Compile `ffmpeg` on CentOS](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos) halfelf referred to just got some cleanups, so try again. It will probably just be easiest to start over.

1. Install `gnutls-devel` or `openssl-devel`.
2. Remove old junk: `rm -rf ~/ffmpeg_build ~/ffmpeg_sources ~/bin/{ffmpeg,ffprobe,ffserver,lame,vsyasm,x264,yasm,ytasm}`
3. Re-run guide.
4. Stop at the FFmpeg section, add `--enable-gnutls` or `--enable-openssl` to the `./configure` line, then continue following the guide.

Or forget compiling and just [download a static build of `ffmpeg`](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/): it has HTTPS support.

Comment: Thanks #LordNeckbeard, i have also solved my issue by following this link  https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/issues/3280